# SIGSEGV on declaration

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Ok, so this is my WHOLE code. I removed everything else.

I can compile it no probs in `codeblocks` but when using an evaluator it gives me `sigsegv`

Makes no sense to me...

It's not because of too much memory allocated btw.

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <cstdio>
     #include <queue>
     #include <cmath>
     using namespace std;

     int n;
     int kx,ky,px,py;
     long long a,b,c;
     struct par
     {
        int x,y;
     };
     long long int bsiter,bsearch;
     par start,stari,novi;
     long long int high[1001][1001];
     int val[1001][1001];
     int ud,rl;

     int main()
     {
        cin >> n >> kx >> ky >> px >> py >> a >> b >> c;
        cout << 0;

        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Does not even compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a namespace conflict in your code:

```
long long int bsiter,bsearch;
```

In `std` there is a function `bsearch`.

Remove `using namespace std;` and write `std::` before `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: you're assuming that the header for `bsearch` is included.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It seems to be for me through `iostream`. (using gcc 4.8.1) Although you are right if this is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change these definitions

```
 long long int high[1001][1001];
 int val[1001][1001];
```

to

```
 static long long int high[1001][1001];
 static int val[1001][1001];
```

Answer (score 0):

`long long int high[1001][1001]` allocates slightly more than 8 MB on the stack.
Some systems have 8 MB as limit for stack size.