# Standard library header hierarchy

Tags: c++, gcc, include

Follow up to my answer to this question: [SIGSEGV on declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066490/sigsegv-on-declaration/21066557#21066557)

In this question the questioner had a problem with a segmentation fault on some simple code. As it turned out it didn't even compile for me and others. GCC (4.8.1) gave an error due to redeclaration of a variable with name `bsearch`, which happens to be identical to a function name in `std`. This resulted in a clash as the code also used `using namespace std;`. Since the questioner accepted my answer I guess this was somehow related with the runtime error (though strange).

The questioner however said the code would compile fine on codeblocks and others confirmed this. `bsearch` should be defined in `cstdlib`, but the code did not include it.

It turned out that gcc includes `cstdlib` if `iostream` is included anyway as one can see from the trace:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test.d" -MT"src/Test.d" -o "src/Test.o" "../src/Test.cpp"
../src/Test.cpp:14:27: error: ‘long long int bsearch’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
      long long int bsiter,bsearch;
                           ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/cstdlib:72:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/bits/basic_string.h:2815,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/string:52,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/Test.o' failed
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/ios:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.1/include/g++-v4/iostream:39,
                 from ../src/Test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:754:14: error: previous declaration of ‘void* bsearch(const void*, const void*, size_t, size_t, __compar_fn_t)’
 extern void *bsearch (const void *__key, const void *__base,
              ^
make: *** [src/Test.o] Error 1
```

It does so only in c++0x and c++11 mode.

Is this structure of includes required, allowed or defined at all in the c++ standards? On cplusplus.com I can find that `iostream` will include `ostream` and `ios`, but there is no information about includes further down.

Comment: There are some include requirements by the standard, but other than that, every standard header is allowed to include any headers it wants

Comment: C++11 §17.6.5.2 Headers [res.on.headers]/1:
"A C++ header may include other C++ headers. ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard mandates in certain places that another header has to be included (e.g., `<iostream>` has to include `<istream>` and `<ostream>`). Otherwise, the standard allows headers to be included and to make declaration available which are not required to become available from a specific header.

I'd think it would be useful to have a system of headers which make exactly those declarations available that are required to be made available but I'm not aware of that being available. These headers could be without actual definitions and would only be used to verify that all necessary headers are included. It might be better to have the headers be part of an actual implementation but that would make the declarations quite a bit more complex.